# Folder sharing for private group

Tags: file-sharing, dropbox

I would like to share a folder with a group (requires some sort of Invite) 
The current structure is:

```
Group/
        User1/
        User2/
        User3/
```

All users (that are invited) can view all the folders, 
but only User1 can edit the files in folder1 
It is crucial that every user can automatically synchronize
his local folder with his Group/User folder 
 
Is there some sort of service that allows such a thing ? 
Tried to do it in Dropbox but it seems that it doesn't allow such complexity

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on Windows Skydrive. It's a little less elegant in Dropbox.

With Dropbox, you create a folder under your account that you only share with certain people.

With Skydrive, you can create a group and that group can be used as a separate entity.

Just set each folder permission level to read only, and have each user create their own folder under their own profile that  they then share with the group.

Comment: not using windows, sorry.
will the read-only thing be possible in Dropbox ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Skydrive also has a browser UI. You can create an invite-only shared folder.  However, you don't get granular permission controls like you desired.